# What would a length contracted object look like?

Tags: special-relativity, visible-light

I have multiple sub-questions but they are related.

- What would the object look like if in were passing by?
- What would a star look like if we were traveling near $c$? Would  the perspective be a a large blue-shifted disk??

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When the finite speed of light – the delay of the rays from the source – is taken into account, one encounters many optical effects aside from "how the world is in relativity effects" such as Lorentz contraction.

Flat lines look like arcs or cicles, one may see "behind himself", and there's of course the Doppler shift of the frequencies depending on the relative speed. Also, streetcars going from left to right are rotated around a vertical axis, and so on.

You may download Real Time Relativity as a great "relativistic 3D game". For a link and other comments on relativistic optical effects, see

> http://motls.blogspot.com/2009/02/relativistic-optical-effects.html?m=1

Comment: Wow! That's great. But I can see, that the perspective distortion makes the distant object even smaller. While getting fryed with blue shifted light from forward.