# Space contraction: what do we see

Tags: special-relativity

[image]

This is my opinion about what we will see. When the pipe arrive at the bar, we will be unable to see some part of it anymore (the pipe will absorb the light emitted by the bar), even if the pipe and the bar didn't appear to us superposed yet. We will not see the white background, because the bar is not transparent. So, we must see nothing (black), even if we know the bar is there. Am I right or wrong?

Comment: We are supposed to be at rest wrt the bar, right? Why would we "be unable to see some part of the bar even if the pipe and the bar don't appear to overlap"?

Comment: Yes, we are at rest. Because the engulfing pipe will absorb the light emitted by the bar. At least, that's what the pipe see: it covers a short bar; it's light can escape.

Comment: You have to select a perspective: 1) what the bar sees, or 2) what the pipe sees. You seem to be mixing both, and that leads to inconsistencies.

Comment: By *seeing*, if you really mean "perceive by a detector" like your camera or eye, then Penrose-Terrell [rotation comes into play](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/47224/11062) when you'll [see the *back* of the objects](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/38783/11062) ;-)

Comment: Interesting. Please draw what a high speed camera will record.